# CsQuery/JQuery can't get element from google search

Tags: c#, jquery, html, google-search, csquery

I'm trying to get the results of a google "define word" search. According to Chrome's Inspect Elements, the text I want is under the class "div class="lr_dct_ent vmod" data-hveid="28"" I'm using this code to try and do it:

```
            var thecq = CQ.CreateFromUrl("https://www.google.be/search?q=define+word&oq=define+word");
            var please = thecq.Select(".lr_dct_ent.vmod").Text();
            var work = thecq[".lr_dct_ent.vmod"].Text();
            Console.WriteLine(please);
            Console.WriteLine(work);
```

neither of these return anything in Console, just empty lines. If I do "div" instead of ".lr_dct_ent.vmod" I get a lot of text and one of them is the text I want which leads me to believe that ".lr_dct_ent.vmod" is not how I'm supposed to search the div class that I wanted. But according to every documentation I found, it IS how I'm supposed to do it. Is Google just a special case or am I the one who's special here?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you need to reference it... Also, have you tried using `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: @ChrisHappy I'm using CsQuery and I already referenced it otherwise "div" would not have given me any results. About the latter suggestion, the thing is I can remove .text() in its entirety and console would still display nothing meaning it just can't find ".lr_dct_ent.vmod" for whatever reason.